# Looking for a way to notify users the list of packages to be updated

Tags: apt

I understand /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available shows the number of packages that needs to be updated but I am looking for a way that shows me the list of all the packages.

Comment: motd messages are NOT generated at login, but at some previous time. The repositories may change between then and now, so the motd number of packages may no longer be accurate.